# Concurrent transactional calls resulting in duplicate responses in .net web service

Tags: asp.net, oracle, transactions

Hi all I have a question on concurrent stored procedure calls from a .net web service written in 3.5 framework.

I am building a web service that is used by many users and needs to return contact information from oracle database.
The issue is when more than 1 user clicks at the same time the db returns the same contact info. I have written the status update query in the SP. I am having this issue only when 2 or more requests read the same record before the status update happens. I have used transaction and transaction-scope but it doesn't solve the issue. Can anyone tell me if i am tackling the problem right or should i be looking at some other way. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ummmm, we have 14 minutes for what?  ...  In any case,  this question needs more info: webservice and SP source code, to start with.  Also need to state the issue better.  What is the expected behavior?  How does it relate to the unexplained "status update query"?  How does it behave when a single user accesses the webservice?  How does it behave when multiple users access it?  I'll retract my downvote if you edit and improve the question.

Comment: The 14 minutes is a typo. Sorry for that.

Comment: The web service calls a Stored procedure which reads a record from the database and updates it status as read. When another user calls the webservice and the previous transaction was still running with the status not having updated then the second user is also getting the same record returned. So 2 users are getting the same record returned when the calls are concurrent. The expected behavior is that each user gets a unique record. If there is no time gap between 2 web service calls then this issue occurs. Please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your stored procedure code is what we term in the trade 'dodgy'.

Generally it should be an

```
UPDATE table
SET status = 'READ'
WHERE ...
RETURNING col_1, col_2 INTO var1, var2;
RETURN;
```

It is probably doing a SELECT then an UPDATE based on ID without checking to see whether the status has been changed by another transaction

Comment: I knew someone with better Oracle/SQL chops than me could provide a more specific answer!  I wish I could upvote twice: once for the solution, and once for use of 'dodgy'.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Your "read" operation on the database isn't really a read, since it updates the record in question.  Sounds like what you need is for the first read-and-update operation to complete and commit before the second read-and-update operation begins.

I'm not a database/oracle guru, so I apologize if this answer is somewhat vague: is there a way to lock the table in question at the start of the read-and-update operation - perhaps an oracle transaction setting?  If so, that should accomplish what you're looking for.

Note that you're essentially single-threading access to that table, which could potentially have performance implications, depending on the number of concurrent users and how often the table is accessed.  You might want to consider alternate ways of accomplishing the requirement.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I tried to set a lock on Read operation but apparently Oracle doesnt allow locking on Select statements unless its a "Select for Update.." which i cant use here. I was wondering if i could set up a queue on the .Net side to regulate the requests to DB. i understand this results in a performance degradation but I need a solution to this issue.

Comment: Gary Myers' solution to this issue looks promising - did it not work for you?  And why are you unable to use "select for update"?

Comment: I have order by and union operators in my query which "Select for Update.." doesn't allow..

Comment: All,

Thanks for all the help on this issue. I really appreciate it.. I however solved the issue by updating immediately after the select query cuz i found out that Oracle just doesn't lock on Select. So in spite of 2 requests reading the same data, the update however is controlled by oracle row locking and happens only one by one. So i used that to my advantage by checking the row status value before performing my operation. It works fine now and the concurrency issue was resolved. Thanks all once again.